# plot coordinates as points with spplot in R

Tags: point, sp

I want to do something that I thought should be relatively simple, but it doesn't seem to work...

I have a SpatialPointsDataframe and a SpatialPolygonsDataframe.

I want to plot all the points I have in the SpatialPointsDataframe together with the lines I have in the SpatialPolygonsDataframe. The name of my SpatialPointsDataframe is *UK.points* and the name of my SpatialPolygonsDataframe is *UK.map*. They both use the same OSGB projection. I try the following:

```
# create outline from the UK.map object
UK.outline <- list("sp.lines", UK.map, col = "black")

# create a variable to plot (all the same value)
UK.points$var1 <- 1

# plot
spplot(UK.points, "var1", cex=0.2, sp.layout = UK.outline, par.settings =
     list(axis.line = list(col =  'transparent')))
```

This gives me the error:

```
Error in cut.default(as.matrix(z), cuts, dig.lab = 4, include.lowest = TRUE) : 
  'breaks' are not unique
```

If var1 has 2 different values, than it does work, but it plots the two different values in 2 different colors. I just want points of all coordinates all black. How to do this?

Comment: Just use base plot and not spplot. To add the polygon call plot again but with add=TRUE

Comment: Thank you! I am trying this, I get the points plotted, but I get errors when trying to add the polygon with baseline plot. What does the plot command to add the polygon look like?